# Laravel 5.8: Route [makeWalletTransaction] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have added a form action like this at my Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('makeWalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$user->usr_id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And on `web.php`:

```
Route::post('wallet/maketransaction/{wallet}/{user}','Wallet\UserWalletController@makeWalletTransaction')->name('user.makeWalletTransaction');
```

And I have also defined this method at the Controller:

```
public function makeWalletTransaction(Request $request, Wallet $wallet, User $user)
```

But I get this error:

```
Route [makeWalletTransaction] not defined.
```

I have also ran these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

But still didn't solve the problem.

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks.

Comment: your route name is `user.makeWalletTransaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basicly the error says that the route parameter you specified it is not defined. In your web.php you named your route `user.makeWalletTransaction`, so change the parameter as well.

```
<form action="{{ route('user.makeWalletTransaction', ['walletId'=>$wallet->id,'userId'=>$user->usr_id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```